# Clojure not catching NumberFormatException

Tags: clojure, numberformatexception

In the following code, Clojure (1.2) is printing the wrong message:

```
(try
  (let [value "1,a"]
    (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (.split value ",")))
  (catch NumberFormatException _ (println "illegal argument")))
```

This should print "illegal argument", but instead it prints a `(1#<NumberFormatException java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a">`.

What am I doing wrong?

Is this because of the lazy sequence returned by `map`? How should it be written?

Comment: You should find this helpful: http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/f4ea5a9c38f4d991

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `try` special form only catches exceptions that are raised during during the dynamic extent of the body code. Here `map` is returning a lazy sequence, which then is passed out of the `try` special form and returned. The printer then evaluates the sequence, and at that point the exception is thrown.

Wrapping the `map` in `doall` should fix your problem.

Comment: I actually tried that. It still seems to return a NFE wrapped in a RuntimeException.

Comment: @Ralph: Under 1.3 it works. You could wrap the parseInt call with try and return some sensible value if an exception occurs. If that is not appropriate, you could return nil when an exception occurs, and check to see if the resulting sequence contains nil to determine if an exception occurred and then act appropriately.

Comment: The second suggestion (return `nil`) sounds reasonable. I'll check that out.

Comment: I tried the `nil` substitution solution and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This example skips invalid solutions using the above `nil` substitution method: ```(let [value "1,a"] (remove nil? (map #(try (Integer/parseInt %) (catch Exception _ nil)) (.split value ","))))```